# Помогите разобраться с PyQt5, а именно с menubar. Буду рад любой помощи

Tags: python, pyqt5, интерфейс, qt-designer

В общем мне надо чтобы когда я переключался в menubar между QMenu (Расчет баллов ВНО, Расчет конкурсного бала,Оценка личностных показателей и Справкой) мне не надо было создавать новые формы, а оставалась та же с меню, просто с другим содержанием, которое я хочу создать отдельно для каждой QMenu(шки). Как я могу это сделать и что для этого надо? Это нужно сделать в QtDesinger или в коде прописать как-то? Я новичок, так что не гнобите. Спасибо, заранее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пока ничего не понятно. Опубликуйте модуль `.ui` и что у вас есть еще. И лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: QStackedWidget. Надо и в дизайнере поработать и в коде соединить менюшки с нужными виджетами в стеквиджете https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QStackedWidget.html